# How can I match the items in an array column, with a different table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery

I have a table that has an array column with a bunch of dog breed guids.  I want to lookup these values and basically return the lookup values instead of the guids.

```
CREATE TABLE dogs(
 name text,
 breeds text[]
);

INSERT INTO dogs (name, breeds) VALUES ('Barkley', '{"abc", "xyz"}');
INSERT INTO dogs (name, breeds) VALUES ('Ponyo', '{"zzz", "xyz"}');

CREATE TABLE breeds(
 guid text,
 breed text
);


INSERT INTO breeds (guid, breed) VALUES ('abc', 'Maltipoo');
INSERT INTO breeds (guid, breed) VALUES ('xyz', 'Jack Russel');
INSERT INTO breeds (guid, breed) VALUES ('zzz', 'Dalmatian');
```

I would like to be able to return the following:

```
Barkley, ['Maltipoo', 'Jack Russel']
Ponyo, ['Jack Russel', 'Dalmatian']
```

Essentially, look them up in my 'breeds' table before returning the values.

Comment: so, BigQuery or Postgresql? clarify please

Comment: BigQuery but usually the Postgres stuff works on BigQuery, so I'd like to see how it's solved on either platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Abusing arrays that way, you first need to convert them to sets using `unnest()`.

```
SELECT d.name,
       concat('[',
              string_agg(concat('''',
                                b.breed,
                                ''''),
                         ', '),
              ']')
       FROM dogs d
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(d.breeds) db
                                                (b)
            LEFT JOIN breeds b
                      ON b.guid = db.b
       GROUP BY d.name;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5bff87c05749926ab06987d57d2c109b)

But what you really should do is to stop abusing arrays and normalize the schema using a linking table.

```
CREATE TABLE dogs
             (name text,
              PRIMARY KEY (name));

CREATE TABLE breeds
             (guid text,
              breed text,
              PRIMARY KEY (guid));

CREATE TABLE dogs_breeds
             (dog text,
              breed text,
              PRIMARY KEY (dog,
                           breed),
              FOREIGN KEY (dog)
                          REFERENCES dogs
                                     (name),
              FOREIGN KEY (breed)
                          REFERENCES breeds
                                     (guid));
                                      
INSERT INTO dogs
            (name)
            VALUES ('Barkley'),
                   ('Ponyo');

INSERT INTO breeds
            (guid,
             breed) VALUES ('abc',
                            'Maltipoo'),
                           ('xyz',
                            'Jack Russel'),
                           ('zzz',
                            'Dalmatian');

INSERT INTO dogs_breeds
            (dog,
             breed)
            VALUES ('Barkley',
                    'abc'),
                   ('Barkley',
                    'xyz'),
                   ('Ponyo',
                    'zzz'),
                   ('Ponyo',
                    'xyz');
```

That way you can declare foreign key constraints and ensure referential integrity.

You can then simply join and aggregate to get your result.

```
SELECT d.name,
       concat('[',
              string_agg(concat('''',
                                b.breed,
                                ''''),
                         ', '),
              ']')
       FROM dogs d
            LEFT JOIN dogs_breeds db
                      ON db.dog = d.name
            LEFT JOIN breeds b
                      ON b.guid = db.breed
       GROUP BY d.name;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e01d3e3903ce8c21045da209658f74f8)

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select name, array(
    select breed from t.breeds guid  
    join breeds using(guid)
  ) breeds
from dogs t
```

If to apply to sample data in your question:

Table `dogs`
[image]

and table `breeds`
[image]

the output is
[image]

Comment: have you tried? does it work for you? if so, consider at least voting up the answer!